# How To Validate CSV column in PHP?

Tags: php, sql, csv

file.csv structure:

[image: file.csv]

Before uploading to folder upload, I want to check the column.

The algorithm is like:

```
if ((column 1 = 'no') && (column 2 = 'product_name') && (column 3 = 'product_price') && (column 4 = 'qty'))
{
    upload();
}  
else
{
    die;
}
```

Is there any coding for this case using php coding or sql to validate?

Answer (score 1):

We have to load the csv file in location and fetch the csv files content and validate the content.

Here is my example:

```
$destination=C:\Users\AIT\Desktop\SC MArgins new.csv;
$contents = file ($destination);
for($i=1; $i<sizeof($contents); $i++)
{ 
$line = trim($contents[$i],'",'); 
 $arr = explode(',',$line);
if($arr[0]=='')
            {
                $rows.='Item#,';
            }

            if($arr[1]=='')
            {
             $rows.='Product Name,';
            }

            if($arr[2]=='')
            {
            $rows.='Product Code,';
            }

            if($arr[3]=='')
            {

            $rows.='Product Grade,';

            }
if($rows!=''){
            $row1.='Row '.$i.'-'. $rows.'can not be empty'."<br>";}
            $k.=$row1;
            }
if($k!='' ){        
            $common->setMsg($row1, 'box_warning');
            return false;
```

}

This code will help u to get which column is missing. Follow this code and let me know if any issues on processing the csv